# Optional span text suffix in vertically centered Flexbox/Bootstrap column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to display a optional text suffix within a vertically centered flexbox/bootstrap column. It should only be displayed on small screens. The following code works, but only if I use the "display:contents" on the span-element, which doesn't have a perfect browser support. If I remove the "display:contents", the text suffix is displayed as another column. How can I make the text suffix flow with the previous text, without using display:contents?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-2">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" width="100" height="300">
   </div> 
   <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
        Title text Title Text 
        <span class="d-lg-none" style="display:contents">
           (Optional column is here on small devices)
        </span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-2 d-none d-lg-flex align-items-center">
      Optional column
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9z81tvsx/

Comment: Try to use css media queries. I think it will answer your question. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### d-flex is `display:flex;`

> The element lays out its contents using flow layout (block-and-inline layout).
>
> If its outer display type is inline or run-in, and it is participating in a block or inline formatting context, then it
> generates an inline box. Otherwise it generates a block container box.
> [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#inside)

You are using `.d-flex` on its parent. Therefore, the `span.d-lg-none` has `display:block` in small size screen. And hence, it behaves like a column.

You can fix the issue by wrapping the text in a Paragraph element.

```
<p>Title text Title Text <span class="d-lg-none" >(Optional column is here on small devices)</span></p>
```